How To Fix Images on Iphone Horizontal Screen
I've noticed that the hands above the portfolio/work section are not appearing as intended on the iphone horizontal view. The two hands dip below the elements below it. How do I fix this?
https://syminadive.com/
It looks fine on desktop and mobile-vertical view

Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? Thanks!

Pls provide your code for help

Just add some top margin on the main element (with class "cd-main-content") which is below the hands


style="margin-top:10px"



